# Google cloud onCreate trigger function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise

I'm trying to integrate a twilio type API in my code so whenever there's a new document added into a collection on firestore I need to trigger this onCreate cloud function

I tried with promises and callbacks and found nothing to be working

```
exports.changeStatus = functions.firestore
  .document("doc_name/{docId}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    var dataString =
      "some text message";
    var options = {
      url:
        "https://..../send/sms",
      method: "POST",
      body: dataString
    };
    return request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        return ;
      } else {
        return error;
      }
    });
  });
```

Help me out to trigger this third party api using promises or some alternatives

Comment: if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        return body;

Comment: request() probably doesn't actually return a promise.  Check the API documentation for the library you're using.  Also consider using a library like request-promise that does return a promise.